# How to sum any amount of user inputted numbers from a single line

Tags: java, sum, user-input

Trying to figure out how I would take any amount of inputted numbers from a user and add them together

Example user input: 1 2 3 4
Sum = 10

The user can put any amount of numbers in not a specified amount so if he wanted to add 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13, it would sum them all up to 91

Thanks for the help in advance.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class test
{
    public static final int SENTINEL = -1;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
        int score = 0;
        int sum = 0;

        System.out.println("Enter numbers here");
        while (score >= 0) {
            if (score <= -1) {
            score = kb.nextInt();
            sum += score;
            score = 0;
        }
            System.out.println(sum);
    }
  }
}
```

---

Thanks to libik for all his time and help, here is the finished code.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class JavaApplication1156 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Enter numbers here");
    int sum;
    do {
        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
        int score = 0;
        sum = 0;
        String line = kb.nextLine();
        kb = new Scanner(line); //has to do this to make the kb.hasNexInt() work.
        while (kb.hasNextInt()) {
            score = kb.nextInt();
            sum += score;
        }
        if (sum <= -1)
        System.out.println("Application ended");
        else if (sum >= 0)
        System.out.println("Sum = " + sum);

    } while (sum != -1);
  }

}
```

Comment: Please show any code you have that attempts to solve the problem, along with any problems you might have encountered, and then you will receive some guidance.  But, we won't do your (home)work for you.

Comment: Have a look at the Scanner class in Java for standard input.
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html

Comment: Nice class name :D :D

Comment: @rgettman Added my code as asked, also not homework but rather doing a little bit extra, as the last thing I did with numbers was adding inputted data from diff int, but thank you for your reply.

Also the problem I was having is it wasn't reading any numbers after the first input Example 123 123 would return 123 not 246.

Comment: @libik LOL sorry I copied the bulk of the code from Lab 20 that was far easier then Lab 19 and I was annoyed, forgot to change it haha.

Also ended up just removing all of the code from the stuff I copied and rewrote it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is very easy actually

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class JavaApplication115 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("write numbers, if you write zero, program ends");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); //just copy-and paste this line, you dont have to understand it yet.
        int number;
        int sum = 0;
        do {
            number = input.nextInt(); //this reads number from input and store its value in variable number
            sum+= number; //here you add number to the total sum
        } while(number != 0); //just repeat cycle as long as number is not zero

        System.out.println("Sum is : " + sum);
    }

}
```

---

Working code based on your code :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
    int score = 0;
    int sum = 0;

    System.out.println("Enter numbers here");
    String line = kb.nextLine();

    kb = new Scanner(line); //has to do this to make the kb.hasNexInt() work.
    while (kb.hasNextInt()) {
        score = kb.nextInt();
        sum += score;
    }
    System.out.println(sum);
}
```

---

Also if you are interested in "minimal" version, which is the same as the one before, but using as less code as possible, here it is :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int sum = 0;
    System.out.println("Enter numbers here");
    Scanner kb = new Scanner((new Scanner(System.in)).nextLine()); //has to do this to make the kb.hasNexInt() work.
    while (kb.hasNextInt()) {
        sum += kb.nextInt();
    }
    System.out.println(sum);
}
```

---

Find sum of each line as long as sum is not zero (based on second block of code) :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Enter numbers here");
    int sum;
    do {
        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
        int score = 0;
        sum = 0;
        String line = kb.nextLine();
        kb = new Scanner(line); //has to do this to make the kb.hasNexInt() work.
        while (kb.hasNextInt()) {
            score = kb.nextInt();
            sum += score;
        }
        System.out.println("Sum = " + sum);
    } while (sum != 0);
}
```

Comment: This works nicely but how would I make it so when I press enter it calculates the sum?

Would I change score to a String and parse it to an int, or something, haha

Also looking at it the code I first tried was very similar to this, till I started changing stuff to see if it would work.

Comment: Nice, thanks for your help, I've never seen the String line = kb.nextLine(); and kb = new Scanner(line); before, will have to do some research on it, but for the mean while, how would I loop the first code you supplied?

Comment: @SamsinOzo - in first code, you can add as much numbers in one line and as much lines you want. Once you write "0", it ends and prints out sum. For example try "1 2 3 4 5" ENTER, "10 20" ENTER, "5 5 5 0" ENTER

Comment: I see what you mean, umm, how would I make it print the sum of each line before enter 

Example 

1 2 3 *enter* 
sum = 6, 1 2 3 4 *enter* sum = 10

Comment: @SamsinOzo - using the second block of code I posted, based on your code and add new while block, look to edit.

Comment: Thank you  for all you help I very much appreciate the time you spent to help me, I added a if statement to finish off the code and it's exactly how I pictured it.  Thanks again!  *See main post for finished code*

Answer (score 1):

//Input the number in a single line (but be in size limit of integer)

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Sum_of_integers {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int num = sc.nextInt();
        int sum = 0;
        while(num >= 1) {  //base value
            int lastval = num % 10;  //the logic
            num = num  / 10;
            sum += lastval;
        }
        System.out.println(sum);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Question - Keep taking numbers as inputs till the user enters ‘x’, after that print sum of all.

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int input = 0;
        int sum = 0;
        while (true){
            sum = sum+input;
            if (input==5){
                System.out.println("Loop is stopped");
                System.out.println("The sum is " + sum);
                break;
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("Take the inputs");
                input = sc.nextInt();
            }
        }
```