# How to take several numbers inputted from one textbox and add them together?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

I know my question may be strange but I want to know. I'm building a program that does inventory. The user inputs numbers from their inventory list for several items in different textboxes and the program stores each input from the textboxes, when the add button is clicked. Then when the user done input numbers from the list. They click a button and it generated an excel file with all the numbers from the textboxes added up. So, far I have the final button event done and the input part done but I'm having trouble getting the inputs from one textbox to stores each one and add all of them up. I have try different method but I can't seem to get it.

My code:

```
    int ALPTotal = 0;
    int memory = 0;

    private void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (txtALP.Text == "")
        {
            txtALP.Text = "0";
        }

        if (txtBookP.Text == "")
        {
            txtBookP.Text = "0";
        }


        string ALP2 = txtALP.Text;
        int ALP = Convert.ToInt32(ALP2);
        string BookP2 = txtBookP.Text;
        int BookP = Convert.ToInt32(BookP2);


        if (ALP >= 150)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter 150 or less", "Item Entered", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
        else if (BookP >= 150)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter 150 or less", "Item Entered", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
        else
        {
        }

        if (memory == 0)
        {
            memory = ALP;
        }
        else if (memory == ALP)
            {
                ALPTotal = memory + ALP + ALP;
                MessageBox.Show("Information Added", "Added to List", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                txtALP.Clear();
                txtBookP.Clear();
             }
     }

 private void btnClearCells_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Excel.Application App;
        Excel.Workbook workbook;
        Excel.Worksheet worksheet;

        App = new Excel.Application();
        workbook = App.Workbooks.Add();
        worksheet = (Excel.Worksheet)workbook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
        worksheet.Cells[3, 2] = ALPTotal;
        worksheet.Cells[4, 2] = txtBookP.Text;
    }
}
```

Also the program should only be able to take up to 100 inputs from each textbox. So, the user shouldn't be able to add more than 100 inputs numbers from each textbox in the program.

So, after trying many different ways and methods, I would like to know: is what I'm asking possible or is it impossible?

P.S. - If more information is needed in order to come up with an answer. Please let me know and I will post more information. Thanks

**UPDATE** I forget to mention earlier that the "btnSubmit_Click" is the add button method and the "btnClearCells_Click" is the Submit/Total button method. Also I added an example of what I want to do in the comments. If anyone not sure what I'm asking here

**FINAL UPDATE** My case is now closed. I have solve my problem and the answer can be seen below. **Thanks to everyone who helped!**

Comment: Why to tag [c++] when it's not. Anyway, [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: What does "100 inputs numbers" mean? If the program is only taking up to 150 items, restrict length to 3? And this: `ALPTotal = memory + ALP + ALP;` makes no sense in the context you provided.

Comment: I tried doing arrays but I keep getting errors, I tried doing a for each loop and get errors. I even did a even did a while loop and get errors. Am I missing something that I keep getting errors?

Comment: (cFrozeDeath) The 150 is the max number that can be entered in a textbox. The 100 is the max number I want that the user to be able to input numbers in textboxes. For example, Like you have 100 orders and you use this program. When you input all the numbers from the 100 orders. Then the program shouldn't be able to take anymore. As for the "ALPTotal = memory + ALP + ALP;" it was one of the methods I tried to get the one textbox to add up to 100 different inputs from the one textbox by the user.

Comment: If you have 2 buttons "Add" and "Submit", then where is Add method's code?

Comment: (Raj Karmal) Funny things about the buttons. I have change the design and button names since the start of the program. The "btnSubmit_Click" is the Add button method and the "btnClearCells_Click" is the Submit button method.

Comment: The most critical part of the question is `I'm having trouble getting the inputs from one textbox to stores each one and add all of them up.` but that's all the detail I can find about what you actually want to do. Do you want to split up a `string` into individual numbers (separated by spaces?) and convert them into `int`s? This is quite unclear, and you could create a much simpler example for that. (Just a console app would do.)

Comment: (31eee384) All I want to do is make a inventory program. One that listed different items and textboxes beside them. Then the user inputs different numbers in the textboxes and click the add button. I want the user to be able to do this up to 100 times. Then when the user hits the Total/Submit, it adds all those numbers from the textboxes together.

Comment: For my example: You have 5 textboxes and 5 items. Paper, Pencils, Books, Pens and Markers. The user enters 5 different numbers for Paper. 5 different numbers for Pencils. 5 different numbers for Book. 5 different numbers for Pens and 5 different numbers for Markers.  Then when the user is done, they hit the Submit or Done Button. The Button then add up the 5 different numbers for Pencils together. 5 different numbers for Book together. 5 different numbers for Pens together and 5 different numbers for Markers together. This is what I want to do. Hope this example helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out my answer. I was reading an question from Stackoverflow.com about "[How to sum any amount of user inputted numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22647352/how-to-sum-any-amount-of-user-inputted-numbers-from-a-single-line)". All I had to do was do add an:

```
memory = ALP;
ALPTotal += memory;
```

Once I added this change to my code and tested it. My program did what I wanted. 
Also thanks to finding my answer, I don't need the 100 user input limit anymore because I thought at first I needed it because I thought I had to do

```
ALPTotal = memory + ALP + ALP + // ALP (97 more times)
```

to get my wanted results but I don't. So, I would like to thank everyone who try to help me solve my problem. Thank you so much.